# Launch Internet Explorer to install program remotely

Tags: windows, powershell

We need to update software on all of out PCs at out office. To update the software you have to login, go to the server URL then it will automatically launch an installer and update the software. Is this possible to do in powershell?

Below code is what I have tried.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("http://127.0.0.1/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant test it (im under linux) but is this what u want?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1,server2 { Start-Process -FilePath "myapp.exe" -ArgumentList "arg1", "arg2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use interactive code like that on a remote machine. For IE to be visible, the user must be logged on interactively.

So, at each computer, the user needs to launch a browser to get the update?
If so, and the site starts the installer, then just use ...

```
Start-Process -FilePath "http://127.0.0.1/"
```

… which starts the default browser as if the user did it.

You could set up a scheduled Task using that command above, and set that scheduled task to run user at logon as long as that user has rights to install or you set the task with the correct admin creds for the install.

If you are trying to do this remotely, you cannot do this interactively, since your session would never log on as another user. PowerShell is not a UI management tool, especially remotely.

Honestly, it would be more prudent just to push this software out over Group Policy or other software distribution system, like SCCM, or download the software to a central workstation / file server, and set a scheduled task to run the installer on the hosts.

Comment: There is nothing about "not locked" in OP, I expect this to be a remote install or update for some software. But anyway, this stuff is better covered up by group policies.